# Using slick carousel in SPFx project. I am loading the Library but getting some weird console errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, slick.js

I am referencing the CSS and JS files like this:

```
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css');
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css');
    SPComponentLoader.loadScript('../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js');
```

When I go into dev tools in chrome and view sources I can go in and all of the files are there.

However in the console I am getting the following errors:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error: Unable to load script https://relative-path.invalid/jquery
    Error loading https://relative-path.invalid/jquery as "jquery" from https://localhost:4321/node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js
```

This is when referencing jQuery through their CDN.  I have also tried referencing it through TypeScripts import statement and using the .loadScript method I am using above.

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

[image: Here I am referencing jQuery and the slick files]

[image: Console errors I am still getting]

[image: No carousel]

Comment: I think you have add jquery as another dependency to your script.

Comment: @user7776232 I have done the npm i --save jquery command.  That should've taken care of it, right?

Comment: no you have to either require/import it . or load it like in your example above

Comment: I was trying it earlier using an import statement but I still got the console errors.  My original thought was maybe because jQuery was know a typescript module and the JS library might not know what to do with it.

Comment: maybe try it like  a normal require statment (requiee

Comment: sry for typo qbove. im typing with my smartphone . your problem is that you don't have a reference to jquery . Try to require or load it before slick and it should work

Comment: @user7776232 You've gotten me that much closer.  I did the loadScript for the jQuery and the console errors have gone away.  However TypeScript complains $ doesn't exist.  If I do    'import * as $ from 'jquery'    as I have done before - it makes the console errors re appear.

Comment: i'll make an answer. It would be good if you tag it as solved so others know what to do.

Comment: sry i read your comment to fast xD i think a var $ = require ('jquery') should do the job .

Comment: @user7776232 No problem. I just tried that and same console errors as when I do the typescript import :(  I uploaded some pics if it helps you understand what's going on any better

Comment: ok i try it like this SPComponentLoader.loadScript ('path/to/jquery', '$') . This hould import it with the global name of jquery.

Comment: This loads jquery properly 'import * as $ from 'jquery'' It seems that actually importing in the jquery is what is causing the errors, for some reason

Comment: That could be, but i never ran over like an inport failure like this. Does it work with the import statement or with the sploader.. one?

Comment: JQuery works with the import statement.  I get the TypeScript intellisense with it.  However, when jquery 'works' it makes those errors appear.  You could try on your own and see if it happens for you.  My project is the yeoman @microsoft/sharepoint generator.  Then I just install jquery and slick-carousel via npm

Comment: @user7776232 This works for me.  However it doesn't look like their examples on the website... but that's a topic for another post I guess, haha!  I took out the loadScript one and instead used .require() down in my render method.

Answer (score 1):

Importing the jQUery like so

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

My class constructor

```
public constructor() {
    super();

    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.css');
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css');
  }
```

My render method:

```
public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML = `
      <div class="container">
        <div class="your-class">
          <div>your content</div>
          <div>your content</div>
          <div>your content</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      `;

      require('../../../node_modules/slick-carousel/slick/slick.js');

      $('.your-class').slick();

  }
```

It's ugly and there's no arrow buttons but I can make it slide by dragging it with my mouse.